# If $F:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is not Lipschitz on $[a,b]$ , then there is a point $x_0 \in [a,b]$ with certain properties.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

Suppose that  $F:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is not Lipschitz in $[a,b]$, then there exists $x_0 \in  [a,b]$ such that for any $\delta(x_0)>0$(delta neighbourhood of $x_0$) there is a sequence $(x_n)$ in $(x_0-\delta(x_0),x_0+\delta(x_0))$ such that $x_n \rightarrow x_0$ and the sequence $\frac{|F(x_0)-F(x_n)|}{|x_0-x_n|}$ does not converge to any real number $L$. Can somebody help me proving this? I need this to prove something.

I have examples:

$\sqrt{x}$ for $x \in [0,\infty]$ is not Lipschitz on $[0,\infty]$  and for any $\delta > 0$ neighbourhood of $0$, we can find a sequence $(x_n)$ that converges  to $0$, and the sequence $\frac{|F(x_0)-F(x_n)|}{|x_0-x_n|}$ does not converge to any real number $L$.

but, I have trouble in the function $F(x)={xsin(\frac{1}{x})}\, \text{for} \,  0<x\leq 1;F(x)=0\, for \, x=0$. I know that $F(x)$ is not Lipschitz in $[0,1]$ maybe because of $0$. But, I can't find a sequence that converges to $0$ and $\frac{|F(x_0)-F(x_n)|}{|x_0-x_n|}$ does not converge to any real number $L$.

Comment: Existence of the limit $\frac{|F(x_0)-F(x_n)|}{|x_0-x_n|}$ will happen if the function is differentiable. On the other hand, Lipschitz can fail due to the derivative being unbounded. Then take a differentiable function with unbounded derivative, like $f(x)=x^2\sin(1/x^2)$ for $x\in(0,1]$ and $f(0)=0$.

Comment: @totoro , then the statment above is false, right?

Comment: Yes, the example I gave is non-Lipschitz on $[0,1]$, but for each point $x_0$ the limits you wanted exist. They converge to the derivative at $x_0$.

Comment: @totoro, even at $x_{0}=0$? (in the example you have given)

Comment: @totoro can you give me some theorems regarding Lipschitz condition that is somewhat similar to the one I posted but correct?

Comment: Yes, at $x_0=0$, the quotients are $\frac{|x^2\sin(1/x^2)|}{|x|}=|x||\sin(1/x^2)|$, which are bounded by $\delta$ for $|x|<\delta$.

Comment: The definition of Lipschitz is similar, the difference is that $x_0$ is allowed to move, keeping the same constant. I think that if you are proving something else, you better post that as a new question. Only seeing it will tell what is the right approach to use.

Comment: tnx..need to try something else.